# tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected() in TensorFlow 2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to use `tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected()` in one of my projects, and it's been deprecated in TensorFlow 2.0. Is there an equivalent function, or should I just keep TensorFlow v1.x in my virtual environment for this project?

Comment: Have you considered tf.keras.layers.Dense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In TensorFlow 2.0 the package `tf.contrib` has been removed (and this was a good choice since the whole package was a huge mix of different projects all placed inside the same box), so you can't use it.

In TensorFlow 2.0 we need to use `tf.keras.layers.Dense` to create a fully connected layer, but more importantly, you have to migrate your codebase to Keras. In fact, you can't define a layer and use it, without creating a `tf.keras.Model` object that uses it.

Answer (score 6):

tf-slim, as a standalone package, already included tf.contrib.layers.you can install by `pip install tf-slim`,call it by `from tf_slim.layers import layers as _layers;  _layers.fully_conntected(..)`.The same as the original, easy to replace

Answer (score 6):

use: `tf.compat.v1.layers.dense`
for example, instead of

```
Z = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(F, num_outputs, activation_fn=None)
```

you can replace it with:

```
Z = tf.compat.v1.layers.dense(F, num_outputs, activation = None)
```

Answer (score 0):

tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected() is a perfect mess. It is a very old historical mark(or a prehistory DNN legacy). Google has completely deprecated the function since Google hated it. There is no any direct function in TensoFlow 2.x to replace tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(). Therefore, it is not worth inquiring and getting to know the function.